# Numpy set all indexes to a value

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy ndarray `a = np.ndarray((3,3))` and I want all of the indexes to start at the same value, e.g. 5:

```
array([[5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5.]])
```

Note: I'm posting this Q&A style because every time I look this up I always find a bunch of random questions about complex slicing, but not a simple example of casting everything at once.  Hopefully this will pop up as a more immediate result next time I search this question.
But I also hope that others have good ideas I can adopt.

Comment: I sense tomfoolery is afoot. You posted and answered your question within one second...

Comment: It's using the stackoverlow Q&A.  I mentioned it in my note at the end of my question.

Comment: Oh I see! I didn't know that was a feature...I thought you had like scripted a way to post a question and then immediately answer it. That's a neat feature :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several alternatives to achieve this, but I think the point will be to analyze which will give you the most optimal results so:

```
In[1]: %timeit np.ones((3,3)) * 5
6.82 µs ± 374 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)    
In[2]: %%timeit
       np.ndarray((3,3))
       a[:] = 5
1.96 µs ± 29.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In[3]: %timeit np.full((3, 3), 5)
4.13 µs ± 59.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

So, probably the best way to do it is creating the array and assigning the value 5 to all elements, that means to use the second option.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some solid ways:

```
# Use the function built for this very purpose
>>> a = np.full((3, 3), 5)
>>> a
array([[5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5.]])
```

or

```
# [:] is shorthand for every index.
>>> a = np.ndarray((3,3))
>>> a[:] = 5
>>> a
array([[5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5.]])
```

or

```
# multiply a single value over every index (currently all 1s)
>>> a = np.ones((3,3)) * 5   
>>> a
array([[5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5.]])
```

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) on indexing for more details and examples of complex indexing/slicing

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have another way of doing this, just use a plus operator:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros((3,3))
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> a + 5
array([[ 5.,  5.,  5.],
       [ 5.,  5.,  5.],
       [ 5.,  5.,  5.]])
>>>
```

(P.S using `zeros` instead of `ndarray`)

Comment: Nice, so it's the same idea as np.ones() * 5

Comment: @loganjones16 Similar, just with plus operator